# Is this proper encapsulation for this Java code? I am confused

Tags: java, encapsulation

Does this Java code involving a `Book` class use proper encapsulation? I feel it can be a lot simpler if I omit some methods but we're required to every method that is in there [especially setters and getters].

Here's the first class:

```
public class Book
{
    private String title;
    private double price;
    private final double SALES_TAX=0.075;

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title=title;
    }
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price=price;
    }
    public double getSalesTax()
    {
        return SALES_TAX;
    }
    public double increasePrice(double incresePrice)
    {
        return incresePrice;
    }
    public double calculateSales(double sales)
    {
        return sales;
    }
}
```

And the second class:

```
public class BookDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

        Book bookOne=new Book();
        Book bookTwo=new Book();

        bookOne.setTitle("Life of Pi");
        System.out.print("Enter number to buy of "+bookOne.getTitle()+": ");
        bookOne.setPrice(13.50*bookOne.calculateSales(keyboard.nextDouble()));
        bookOne.setPrice((bookOne.getPrice()*bookOne.getSalesTax())+bookOne.getPrice());
        System.out.print("Cost for "+bookOne.getTitle()+" $");
        System.out.printf("%.2f"+"\n",bookOne.getPrice());

        bookTwo.setTitle("Harry Potter: The Goblet Of Fire");
        System.out.print("Enter number to buy of "+bookTwo.getTitle()+": ");
        bookTwo.setPrice(22.00*bookTwo.calculateSales(keyboard.nextDouble()));
        bookTwo.setPrice((bookTwo.getPrice()*bookTwo.getSalesTax())+bookTwo.getPrice());
        System.out.print("Cost for "+bookTwo.getTitle()+" $");
        System.out.printf("%.2f"+"\n",bookTwo.getPrice());

        System.out.print("Enter percent increase of "+bookOne.getTitle()+": ");
        bookOne.setPrice((bookOne.getPrice()*bookOne.increasePrice(keyboard.nextDouble()))+bookOne.getPrice());
        System.out.printf("Cost of "+bookOne.getTitle()+": $"+"%.2f"+"\n",bookOne.getPrice());

        System.out.print("Enter percent increase of "+bookTwo.getTitle()+": ");
        bookTwo.setPrice((bookTwo.getPrice()*bookTwo.increasePrice(keyboard.nextDouble()))+bookTwo.getPrice());
        System.out.printf("Cost of "+bookTwo.getTitle()+": $"+"%.2f"+"\n",bookTwo.getPrice());

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

I know that this is a lot so I'm not really expecting much in terms of a response but anything would help. Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "proper"?

Comment: Someone heard fields broke encapsulation (which they do). Thus, in a moment of Javabeanism, they wrapped all the fields in getters and setters. And while this does 'allow one to change the implementation' and 'use interfaces' - for, you know, 'encapsulation' - it really didn't fix the fundamental problem..

Comment: My recommendation would be to remove the setters that are not required (if they are over immutable fields; and in either case I would take the initial values through the constructor) and then to implement the other methods such that they *actually* do what they claim to do - either appropriately increase ("set") the price or calculate and return the sales value.

Comment: The sales tax logic should be inside the `Book` class. Declare `SALES_TAX` as `private static final` and get rid of the getter. `Book` can have `getPriceWithTax()` which would return `price * (SALES_TAX + 1)`.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't be storing your prices as doubles, use longs and store the price as cents/centimes/pence/etc. This obviously means parsing your user's input differently, but it will make for much safer calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the point of encapsulation. You have a Class which consists of properties and methods. The idea behind encapsulation is, you want the methods in your class to be the only way to change the value (state) of the properties. Think of it like this: if some other code in the program wants to change the value of one of the properties, it cannot do it itself, it must ask a method on the class they reside in to do it. That way, you control access to the properties.

The way this is implemented is with getter and setter methods of which you have created a few. A getter method returns the value of the property and a setter method changes it to a new value.

**1.**

Your getter and setter methods up to increasePrice() are good. You are preventing access to the properties other than from the methods on your class.

**2.**

increasePrice() only spits out what was passed into it. It doesn't change the value of any of the properties and thus has no purpose. If you want to be able to increase the price you can change the method like so:

```
  public void increasePrice(double amountOfPriceIncrease) {

    price += amountOfPriceIncrease;
     /* 
     price += amountOfPriceIncrease is the same as 
     price = price + amountOfPriceIncrease
     */

    }
```

**3.**
This line is a bit troubling. For starters, increasePrice() doesn't do anything other than spit out what was put into it and secondly, there is a lot going on in the one line that makes it complicated and hard to follow.

```
bookTwo.setPrice((bookTwo.getPrice()*bookTwo.increasePrice(keyboard.nextDouble()))+bookTwo.getPrice());
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont necessarily need all the setters. For example, its probably reasonable to assume that a book has a title, and it doesnt change. So you can make it final, omit the setter, and pass it into the constructor.

Also, think about how you're modelling things. Is sales tax a property of a book? I'd say not.

Answer (score 1):

The last two methods do not make much sense. You simply return what you put in. Do it this way:

```
public double increasePrice(double increase)
{
    price *= increase;
}
public double calculateSales(double sales)
{
    //return {your formula}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because all the required variables `title, price` for class `Book` are set to private, and that access can only be used using `get..()`, and changing it if possible can only be used using `set..(some variable)` or an instance method affecting one of the fields, it demonstrates **proper encapsulation**, so all getting and setting are regulated.

However, I spotted several mistakes in `BookDriver`, namely with the improper usage of `Book` fields.
The `price` should change only through `setPrice` or `increasePrice`.
You should also implement `getPriceAfterTax` to determine after-tax prices for a book.
The total cost of the books you bought should not involve any `setPrice`.

There is a mistake with `public double calculateSales(double sales)`. It does nothing but returns back `sales`. The `calculateSales` should calculate the total cost of the book(s) being bought, using one int variable, and you also resorted in changing the price of these books, which shouldn't happen. It is the reason why you wrote messy code, as in the excerpt

```
bookTwo.setPrice(22.00*bookTwo.calculateSales(keyboard.nextDouble()));
bookTwo.setPrice((bookTwo.getPrice()*bookTwo.getSalesTax())+bookTwo.getPrice());
```

This avoids the potential case of changing the values of that `BOOK` object to unexpected or unusual values and value combinations.

Additionally, `SALES_TAX` can be made into a `public static final double` instead, as it is assumed to never change, and you can simply obtain `SALE_TAX` without requiring `getSalesTax()`.